# Remove some text in string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<td colspan="2" class="ai1ec-time">
    <a class="ai1ec-button ai1ec-calendar-link" href="#">
         Back to Calendar »                
    </a>
    July 12, 2012 @ 08:00 am – July 13, 2012 @ 10:00 pm
</td>​
```

Above is my HTML markup which display the text below.

Back to Calendar »                
                July 12, 2012 @ 08:00 am – July 13, 2012 @ 10:00 pm            ​

I need to remove `@ 08:00 am` from the starting date/time and `@ 10:00 pm` from the ending date/time. How can this be done with jQuery? I heard and read of something called Regexp, is that what needs to be used? With jQuery remove()?

I forgot to mention that the 'time' is not fixed. The only thing that's fixed is that the portion that needs to be removed starts with '@' and ends with 'm'

Comment: Will the parts being removed always be "@ 08:00 am" and "@ 10:00 pm"?

Comment: Nope. The time will vary. But it will always start with @

Comment: Is it possible to alter the html in anyway, wrapping elements in spans, or using data attributes to make targeting easier?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I checked out the PHP function that returns the value. It's all bundled together and I have no idea how to edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".ai1ec-time").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace( /@[0-9:\s]+(am|pm)/ig, '' );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ozuwob/2/edit

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Let me try this now

Comment: @IwaniKhalid Did you have any luck?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pLAnd/1/ Unfortunately no, on jsfiddle. Wonder if it's the rendering engine

Comment: I tested it on the live site and it works! Yay! Thank you Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

first make sure you have jQuery running ( [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) )

Then use something like this:

```
$(".ai1ec-time").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace( /\@\s\d\d\:\d\d\s(am|pm)/ig, '' );
});
```

demo: [js bin](http://jsbin.com/ozuwob/3/edit)

Comment: Yeah, its not only 8am and 10am. That's the tough bit for me

Comment: It would not work cause you are passing string instead of regexp, and AFAIK .replace() does not change caller-string, it only returns new string. So you must make smth like obj.html(obj.html().replace())

Comment: Thanks @scubaFLY and caligula for your time and answers. Appreciate it so much :)

Comment: check out @Jonathan Sampson answer that one is working. also updated mine so it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $td = $('td.ai1ec-time')
$td.html($td.html().replace(/@ \d{1,2}:\d{2} [ap]m/g, ''))
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here? Doesn't seem to be working http://jsfiddle.net/mTpCn/2/

Comment: javascript variables don't start with a `$` as far as i know

Comment: I managed to get it working with [Jonathan's answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459932/remove-some-text-in-string-with-jquery/10459994#10459994)

Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: reason was in table layout. You had to not omit <table> and <tr> tags